# Difficulty converting function to a single equation (constexpr)

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I was converting a lot of the bit-operating functions of my code base into `constexpr`. No real reason for doing so, mostly 'just because'.

Making a function constexpr in C++11 requires that the code be a single expression, which isn't always possible (and isn't always desired).

Anyway, I am having some trouble with this function:

```
//Given a binary value like 00000100011, fills every bit below the highest '1' bit with a '1'.
//Example: 00000100011 -> 00000111111
inline uint32_t FillUntilHighestBit(uint32_t value)
{
    value |= (value >> 1);
    value |= (value >> 2);
    value |= (value >> 4);
    value |= (value >> 8);
    value |= (value >> 16);

    return value;
}
```

Here's one attempt I wrote: http://ideone.com/BeQZUH

```
return (value |= (value |= (value |= (value |= (value |= (value >> 1)) >> 2) >> 4) >> 8) >> 16);
```

The problem is, `constexpr` doesn't allow modifying variables or storing the results in variables, so the compound OR assignment |= operator is out.

This means that to put the function in a single equation, I'd have to do a copious amount more ORs and bit shifts, because I can't store the intermediate results in a variable.

Anyone see any way around this, or have a better equation that is valid constexpr that provides the same result?
It's not a critical issue for me, but was the only one of a group of functions that I couldn't convert to `constexpr`, and sits there in their midst taunting me. =)

Comment: Why not just `return value | value >> 1 | value >> 2...`?

Comment: @chris if the function is evaluated at runtime (maybe given a non-const value), that would be slower (requiring 31 bitshifts and ORs). My answer below shows how to do it in a way which has the same runtime performance.

Comment: @Dave, Ah, my mistake. They're not identical. I did something wrong in simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call another constexpr from within a constexpr, so you can write it as:

```
constexpr uint32_t internalFunc(uint32_t value,int s) {
    return (value >> s) | value;
}
constexpr uint32_t FillUntilHighestBit(uint32_t value) {
    return internalFunc(
     internalFunc(
      internalFunc(
       internalFunc(
        internalFunc(value,1)
       ,2)
      ,4)
     ,8)
    ,16);
}
```

Also, your original function is or-ing with value twice in each line.

Comment: Whoops, you're right (about the double ORs)! That was a mistake while trying to convert it.
This works perfectly - I hadn't considered breaking it into separate functions.